# Port multiplexer sslh: why is it so resource-intensive?

Tags: debian, networking, vps

I've just discovered the existence of `sslh`.

I tried to install it on my 512MB RAM VPS running Debian 7 wheezy. After having configured `sslh`, I tried to connect to one of my apache2 virtual hosts, and immediately the cpu usage went up to 50-60%, even ssh-ing the VPS was almost impossible due to the lack of resources.

- Is this normal?
- Is there any valid alternative?

The problem I was trying to solve using `sslh` is that many free wifi hotspots block almost every port, except 80 and 443, and I often need to use OpenVPN to connect to my home server, which is natted by my ISP.

Do you have any other solution to suggest?

Comment: You should open a ticket on the sslh bugtracker (https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh/issues)

Comment: I will do it, good suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a casual review of the source, it appears the author(s) were overzealous in their use of `set_nonblock` in [sslh-select.c](https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh/blob/master/sslh-select.c).

If you flag every socket (as it does) as non-blocking, the the loop

```
while(1) {
    select(… a bunch of non-blocking sockets …);
}
```

at around line 230 in the linked file becomes a busy-wait. That is, even if there is no data available to read on any socket, select returns instantly and then gets called again immediately. This is rather processor intensive.

The author came close to getting it right, with some conditional use of the `timeout` argument to `select` but that has no effect if all are set to non-blocking anyway.

I didn't profile `sslh` which is he best way to confirm this is the real cause.

Comment: That was a very exhaustive answer! Could you please suggest an alternative that is not so processor intensive to solve my problem? I found `sshttp`, do you think it will be so demanding of resources? Thank you.

Comment: The problem with sslh is an outright bug. I find it hard to believe that another program like sshttp would make the same mistake. Unfortunately, I have no interest in benchmarking port multiplexors; good luck.

Answer (score 3):

So this issue is now followed here: https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh/issues/24

msw's answer might be exhaustive, but is also wrong: `select()` will block regardless of the socket's `O_NONBLOCK` status, that's basically what it's there for, and in fact code that uses blocking sockets when using `select()` is wrong. From Linux' `select(2)`: "Under Linux, `select()` may report a socket file  descriptor  as  "ready for reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks".

In other words, not setting `O_NONBLOCK` while using `select()` may result in complete blockage of the program.

So, while something might be wrong, this is not it.